# Slow GDB response with C++ templatized codebase

Tags: c++, gcc, gdb

I have recently encountered slow responses from GDB while debugging.

`ptype <namespace::variable_name>` is taking over a minute for me.

I have tried running strace to track what calls are making GDB stuck. On executing command `ptype <namespace::variable_name>`, I see around 5000 LSEEK calls being made. Each call is for the same offset. Here are the logs for the same -

```
lseek(158, 4980736, SEEK_SET)           = 4980736
lseek(158, 4980736, SEEK_SET)           = 4980736
lseek(158, 4980736, SEEK_SET)           = 4980736
lseek(158, 4980736, SEEK_SET)           = 4980736
lseek(158, 4980736, SEEK_SET)           = 4980736
lseek(158, 4980736, SEEK_SET)           = 4980736
lseek(158, 4980736, SEEK_SET)           = 4980736
lseek(158, 4980736, SEEK_SET)           = 4980736
ptrace(PTRACE_PEEKTEXT, 865894, 0x7fffe0ccb260, [0x7fffe3a0c920]) = 0
rt_sigaction(SIGINT, {sa_handler=0x556e929a32e0, sa_mask=[INT], sa_flags=SA_RESTORER|SA_RESTART, sa_restorer=0x7fb93304d090}, {sa_handler=0x556e929a32e0, sa_mask=[INT], sa_flags=SA_RESTORER|SA_RESTART, s>
brk(0x556ec2ea5000)                     = 0x556ec2ea5000
brk(0x556ec2ec6000)                     = 0x556ec2ec6000
brk(0x556ec2ee7000)                     = 0x556ec2ee7000
brk(0x556ec2f08000)                     = 0x556ec2f08000
brk(0x556ec2f29000)                     = 0x556ec2f29000
brk(0x556ec2f4a000)                     = 0x556ec2f4a000
```

It seems like demangling is causing the problem. When I set demangle-style to none using `set demangle-style none`, then the same command `ptype <mangled-name>` takes a second to respond.

However, debugging using mangled names is very inconvenient. So i am looking for a solution to fix the 5k LSEEK issue.

Can someone please help debug this?

Expectation is that `ptype <namespace::variable_name>` should return response in < 5 seconds as it normally does.

Environment Details:

- GDB Version: GNU gdb (Ubuntu 9.2-0ubuntu1~20.04.1) 9.2
- OS: Linux 5.4.0-135-generic #152-Ubuntu SMP Wed Nov 23 20:19:22 UTC 2022 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
- gcc version 9.4.0 (Ubuntu 9.4.0-1ubuntu1~20.04.1)
- GDB: This GDB was configured as "x86_64-linux-gnu"
- Total size of all .so files being linked: 350 MBs

**Update:**
I had BOOST_FORCEINLINE around 90% of the functions which were all member functions to some template class. Once i removed BOOST_FORCEINLINE keyword, gdb ptype/print issue got resolved. Size of the so files is still the same as before. I can't understand why force inlining might cause gdb slowness. Any thoughts?

Comment: Which version of gdb? Which platform? How big is your executable?

Comment: GDB 9.2. Tried with GDB version 13.2 as well but getting same issue. Using Ubuntu-20 machine (Linux x86). I have multiple .so files being linked together. Total size of all .so files combined is 350 MBs

Comment: These details should be [edit]ed into your question

Comment: I would report it as a GDB bug.

Comment: I have done the same https://sourceware.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=31048. Just wanted to post here as well in case someone has already faced something similar and they can help me out.

Comment: I guess it's not easy to create a small reproducer.

Comment: Codebase i have been using has 350MBs worth of code written across many years. So reproducing that big a set of binaries seems to be difficult unfortunately

Comment: Can you get a stack trace of GDB at one of those 5000 lseek calls?

Comment: Can you show us the type of the variable that causes the problem? Replace components of the type name with As, Bs, Cs, etc if the name would otherwise reveal proprietary info.

Comment: Removing BOOST_FORCEINLINE from class member functions seems to have fixed the problem. Size of the so files hasn't changed. Can't understand how inlining functions can cause GDB to slowdown.
P.S. 90% of the class member functions had BOOST_FORCEINLINE, so roughly 20 functions were affected in the change